# Load file from resources by relative path (Spring)

Tags: java, spring

I have spring project.  My file here: /src/main/java/resources/file.txt.

How I can get full path of this?

If I run from test it works:

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/java/resources/file.txt";
```

But if I use tomcat, it shows another path inside tomcat folder. So spring cannot find this path.

**EDIT:** this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file.txt") is null

**UPDATED**: sorry for stupid question. It works, I set wrong name of file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As file - `file.txt` is in resources directory, normally this would be copied to `class-path` by build process(tool like Maven, Gradle). And this would easy with to load file with relative path.

This thread had extensively talked about how to load file from `class-path`.
[How to really read text file from classpath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

The relative path depends on the current context context: Application, library,....

You can dig documentation or simply add something like

```
File fn = new File("resources/database.db");
logger.info(fn.getAbsolutePath());
```

To see where the current path is in that moment.

For example, to create SQLite datasource in the Spring @Configuration block

```
@Configuration
.....
@Bean
....
        String dbName="database.sqlite";
        File fn = new File("src/main/resources/"+dbName);
        String name=fn.toURI().toString();
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:sqlite:"+name );
....
```

Answer (score 0):

With Spring you can use class [`ClassPathResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html). It can read files from java classpath without too much pure Java boilerplate code.